# Create view with delta for each column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, lag, delta

I have a table named `pwrDay` containing electric index counters (always growing).

| jour | pwrconsohp | pwrconsohc | pwrprod | pwrprodmax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-26 | 35 736 527 | 18 073 331 | 12 629 677 | 0 |
| 2021-09-27 | 35 754 125 | 18 073 331 | 12 637 154 | 0 |
| 2021-09-28 | 35 780 113 | 18 073 331 | 12 646 963 | 0 |
| 2021-09-29 | 35 807 081 | 18 073 331 | 12 657 084 | 0 |
| 2021-09-30 | 35 833 193 | 18 073 331 | 12 668 804 | 0 |
| 2021-10-01 | 35 861 259 | 18 073 331 | 12 682 444 | 0 |
| 2021-10-02 | 35 888 342 | 18 073 331 | 12 693 908 | 0 |
| 2021-10-03 | 35 917 218 | 18 073 331 | 12 704 696 | 0 |
| 2021-10-04 | 35 944 869 | 18 073 331 | 12 706 056 | 0 |
| 2021-10-05 | 35 972 043 | 18 073 331 | 12 708 309 | 0 |

I need to extract the difference between previous and current row (maybe create a view?) The following query works for most days, but it's wrong every first day of month (or if I miss a control day):

```
SELECT  pwr.jour,
        (pwr.pwrconsoHP-ifnull(oldpwr.pwrconsoHP, 0)) as deltaconsoHP,
        (pwr.pwrconsoHC-ifnull(oldpwr.pwrconsoHC, 0)) as deltaconsoHC,
        (pwr.pwrProd-ifnull(oldpwr.pwrProd, 0)) as deltaProd    
FROM pwrDay pwr
LEFT OUTER JOIN pwrDay oldpwr ON 
(day(pwr.jour)-day(oldpwr.jour)=1 AND MONTH(pwr.jour)=MONTH(oldpwr.jour))
ORDER BY jour;
```

I also tried this query:

```
SELECT  pwr.jour,
        (pwr.pwrconsoHP-LAG(pwr.pwrconsoHP, 0)) as deltaconsoHP,
        (pwr.pwrconsoHC-LAG(pwr.pwrconsoHC, 0)) as deltaconsoHC,
        (pwr.pwrProd-LAG(pwr.pwrProd, 0)) as deltaProd
FROM pwrDay pwr
ORDER BY jour;
```

However, it doesn't run at all. I get this error message:

> Erreur SQL (1305) : FUNCTION velbus.LAG does not exist

How can I write this query?

Comment: `LAG()` needs in OVER clause (window specifying). And `LAG(column, 0)` == `column`

Comment: [LAG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) function is only available from version 8.0 and later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  pwr.jour,
        (pwr.pwrconsoHP-LAG(pwr.pwrconsoHP, 0) OVER(order by jour)) as deltaconsoHP,
        (pwr.pwrconsoHC-LAG(pwr.pwrconsoHC, 0) OVER(order by jour)) as deltaconsoHC,
        (pwr.pwrProd-LAG(pwr.pwrProd, 0)  OVER(order by jour)) as deltaProd
FROM pwrDay pwr
ORDER BY jour;
```

give it a try ...

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, I've got : 
Erreur SQL (1064) : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OVER(ORDER BY jour)) as deltaconsoHP, (pwr.pwrconsoHC-LAG(pwr.pwrconsoHC, 0)' at line 2

Comment: Seems to be mariadb version (lag() come with 10.2 and I'm using
 $ mysqld --version
mysqld  Ver 10.1.48-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 for debian-linux-gnueabihf on armv7l (Raspbian 9.11)

Comment: It works like a charm with changing 0 by 1 in lag() function.
My problem was linked with raspian OS (v9 'strech') which could not include mariadb 10.2+... I've upgrade it to v10 'buster' and now it's ok, thanks.